# scala spark, how do I merge a set of columns to a single one on a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm looking for a way to do this without a UDF, I am wondering if its possible. Lets say I have a DF as follows:

```
Buyer_name  Buyer_state  CoBuyer_name  CoBuyers_state  Price  Date
Bob         CA           Joe           CA              20     010119
Stacy       IL           Jamie         IL              50     020419
... about 3 millions more rows...
```

And I want to turn it to:

```
Buyer_name Buyer_state Price Date
Bob        CA          20    010119
Joe        CA          20    010119
Stacy      IL          50    020419
Jamie      IL          50    020419
...
```

Edit: I could also,

Create two dataframes, removing "Buyer" columns from one, and "Cobuyer" columns from the other.

Rename dataframe with "Cobuyer" columns as "Buyer" columns.

Concatenate both dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group `struct(Buyer_name, Buyer_state)` and `struct(CoBuyer_name, CoBuyer_state)` into an `Array` which is then expanded using `explode`, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("Bob", "CA", "Joe", "CA", 20, "010119"),
  ("Stacy", "IL", "Jamie", "IL", 50, "020419")
).toDF("Buyer_name", "Buyer_state", "CoBuyer_name", "CoBuyer_state", "Price", "Date")

df.
  withColumn("Buyers", array(
    struct($"Buyer_name".as("_1"), $"Buyer_state".as("_2")),
    struct($"CoBuyer_name".as("_1"), $"CoBuyer_state".as("_2"))
  )).
  withColumn("Buyer", explode($"Buyers")).
  select(
    $"Buyer._1".as("Buyer_name"), $"Buyer._2".as("Buyer_state"), $"Price", $"Date"
  ).show
// +----------+-----------+-----+------+
// |Buyer_name|Buyer_state|Price|  Date|
// +----------+-----------+-----+------+
// |       Bob|         CA|   20|010119|
// |       Joe|         CA|   20|010119|
// |     Stacy|         IL|   50|020419|
// |     Jamie|         IL|   50|020419|
// +----------+-----------+-----+------+
```

Comment: Great answer Leo, I have added an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an unpivot operation to me which can be accomplished with the `union` function in Scala:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Bob", "CA", "Joe", "CA", 20, "010119"),
  ("Stacy", "IL", "Jamie", "IL", 50, "020419")
).toDF("Buyer_name", "Buyer_state", "CoBuyer_name", "CoBuyer_state", "Price", "Date")

val df_new = df.select("Buyer_name", "Buyer_state", "Price", "Date").union(df.select("CoBuyer_name", "CoBuyer_state", "Price", "Date"))

df_new.show
```

Thanks to Leo for providing the dataframe definition which I've re-used.